# Making the style's binding more flexible

Tags: wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to make the existing style more flexible.
I'm attaching a dep. property to the double click event of the data grid row control.
On double-clicking the row i want a certain window to open.
To achieve this I've implemented a dep. property and added a style definition.
Below is the part from the view file:

```
<Style x:Key="SomeKey" TargetType={x:Type DataGridRow} BasedOn= "SomeOtherKey">
    <Setter Property="vm:DataGridBehavior:OnDoubleClick" Value="{Binding Path=CommandName,
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

the attached property hooks to the double-click event on the data row
and executes the relay command bound to the view.
I'd like to enable more flexibility in the style
by specifying the command-to-be-invoked name in the view itself (as it may differ between different views).
How can I achieve that?
Is there any template definition that I'm missing?
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass `DataGrid` and add a Property for the Command, e.g MyCommand. Then you could bind that ICommand in each `DataGrid` and use MyCommand as Path in the RowStyle Binding

**DataGrids**

```
<local:CommandDataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource SomeKey}"
                       MyCommand="{Binding CommandName1}">
<!-- ... -->
<local:CommandDataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource SomeKey}"
                       MyCommand="{Binding CommandName2}">
```

**RowStyle**

```
<Style x:Key="SomeKey" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="vm:DataGridBehavior.OnDoubleClick"
            Value="{Binding Path=MyCommand,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
</Style>
```

**CommandDataGrid**

```
public class CommandDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyCommand",
                                    typeof(ICommand),
                                    typeof(CommandDataGrid),
                                    new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(MyCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyCommandProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could create an attached property e.g MyCommand that you use

**DataGrid**

```
<DataGrid vm:DataGridBehavior.MyCommand="{Binding CommandName}"
```

**RowStyle**

```
<Style x:Key="SomeKey" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="vm:DataGridBehavior.OnDoubleClick"
            Value="{Binding Path=(vm:DataGridBehavior.MyCommand),
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
</Style>
```

**MyCommandProperty**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyCommand",
                                        typeof(ICommand),
                                        typeof(DataGridBehavior),
                                        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
public static void SetMyCommand(DependencyObject element, ICommand value)
{
    element.SetValue(MyCommandProperty, value);
}
public static ICommand GetMyCommand(DependencyObject element)
{
    return (ICommand)element.GetValue(MyCommandProperty);
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot :) This works and that's amazing.
I was wondering if you could think of any non-subclass solution enabling me to leave the view's xaml intact (still using the DataGrid and not another subclass)?

Comment: @Gena Verdel: See my updated answer. You could use an attached property